# Ffmpeg add audio to video WITHOUT generating a new output file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I Know how to add audio to video with Ffmpeg. But it works like that :

This is the input
- Video.mov (mute)
- Audio.wav

This is the output
VideoWithSound.mov

Is it possible to add audio to the video without generating a new file ? Simple by modifying the Input file ?

My command line is :

ffmpeg -probesize 50M -analyzeduration 100M -i /Users/xxx/Documents/ReplaceScript/video.mov -i /Users/xxx/Documents/ReplaceScript/Audio.wav -af apad -shortest -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:a pcm_s24le -async 1 -t " & valeur & " -c:v copy -aspect 16:9 -metadata creation_time=now -sn -y /Users/xxx/Documents/ReplaceScript/VideoWithSound.mov

Comment: Not possible. `ffmpeg` can't modify a file in-place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible.

You have to delete the old file and rename the new one.